# The image only collides with part of the other image

Tags: python

I am trying to make an air hockey game on pygame and am having problems with vectors and collisions.
I am new to programming and pygame and am not very confident with sprites so I tried to do collisions using distances. Here is my code:(I do not know how to post the Images but basically the player has the right half and the computer has the left half with the middle being at 350. Another problem that I have is that the computer player moves too fast)

```
     import pygame, sys
from random import randint
from pygame.locals import *
import time

#defines the colours
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
green = (0,255,0)
red = (255,0,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
yellow= (255,242,0)
pygame.init()
size = 700,500
#where the computers mallet is drawn
xPos = randint(1,320)
yPos = randint(30,500)
aPos = 350
bPos = 250
xSpeed = 0
ySpeed = 0
score=0
OppScore=0
diffx = 0
diffy = 0
OppDiffx = 0
OppDiffy = 0
vdiffx = 0
vdiffy = 0
LastPosx = 0
LastPosy = 0
moving = 0
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Electro Air Hockey")

done = False
CompletedAll = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def PlayerMallets():
    global x,y
    global Mallet
    global xSpeed
    global xPos
    global vdiffx
    global LastPosx
    global vdiffy
    global LastPosy
    global moving
    pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
    BackFrame = pygame.image.load("C:\Users\DOAA\Desktop\Coding\Python\ElectroAirHockey\E_A_H_Background.png").convert_alpha()
    Mallet = pygame.image.load("C:\Users\DOAA\Desktop\Coding\Python\ElectroAirHockey\Mallet_Trans.png").convert_alpha()
    OppMallet=pygame.image.load("C:\Users\DOAA\Desktop\Coding\Python\ElectroAirHockey\OppMallet_Trans.png").convert_alpha()
    #the players mallet position is the same as the mouse position
    x,y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    x -= Mallet.get_width()/2
    y -= Mallet.get_height()/2
    #$sets the boundaries for the player
    if x <350:
        x = 350
    if x > 670:
        x = 670
    if y <0:
        y=0
    if y >470:
        y=470
    screen.blit(BackFrame, (0,0))
    screen.blit(Mallet, (x,y))
    yPos = bPos
    xPos = xPos+randint(-2,2)
    screen.blit(OppMallet, (xPos, yPos))
    #this is the part where I started attempting to use vectors by seeing if the player is moving in the same direction that he was in last time
    #xSpeed = xSpeed + 1
    if vdiffx ==0 and LastPosx==0 and moving== 0 and vdiffy==0 and LastPosy==0:
        LastPosx = x
        LastPosy = y
        moving = 1
    if moving == 1:
        vdiffx = x-LastPosx
        vdiffy = y-LastPosy


def Puck():
    global aPos
    global bPos
    global xSpeed
    global ySpeed
    global score
    global OppScore
    if aPos < 0:
        #xSpeed = 0-xSpeed
        #ySpeed = 0-ySpeed
        if bPos>= 118 and bPos<=386:
            xSpeed = 0
            aPos = 350
            bPos=250
            ySpeed=0
            score = score + 1
            #xSpeed = 0-xSpeed
            #ySpeed = 0-ySpeed
        elif aPos < 0:
            if bPos<118 or bPos>386:
                if xSpeed<0:
                    xSpeed=xSpeed+1
                    xSpeed = 0-xSpeed
                    ySpeed = 0-ySpeed
                if xSpeed>0:
                    xSpeed=xSpeed-1

                #ySpeed = 0-ySpeed
    if aPos > 640:
        if bPos>= 118 and bPos<=386:
            xSpeed = 0
            aPos = 350
            bPos=250
            ySpeed=0
            OppScore = OppScore + 1
            #xSpeed = 0-xSpeed
            #ySpeed = 0-ySpeed
        elif aPos > 680:
            if bPos<118 or bPos>386:
                xSpeed = 0-xSpeed
                #ySpeed = 0-ySpeed
    if bPos < 0:
        #xSpeed = 0-xSpeed
        ySpeed = 0-ySpeed
    if bPos >470:
        #xSpeed = 0-xSpeed
        ySpeed = 0-ySpeed
    aPos=aPos+xSpeed
    bPos=bPos-ySpeed
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, yellow, [aPos, bPos], 15)




def Collision():
    global xSpeed
    global ySpeed
    global xPos
    global diffx
    global diffy
    global OppDiffx
    global OppDiffy
    #if x== aPos  and y==bPos  and xSpeed == 0 and x>=350:
    #if pygame.sprite.collide_circle(Puck, Mallet):
#   is_a_collision = pygame.sprite.collide_mask(Mallet, Puck)
#   if is_a_collision == True:
# this part checks if they are in the same range because they have a radius of 15
    if x>aPos:
        diffx=x-aPos
    if x<aPos:
        diffx=aPos-x
    if y>bPos:
        diffy=y-bPos
    if y<bPos:
        diffy=bPos-y
    if diffx <= 15 and diffy <= 15:
        #xSpeed = xSpeed+1
        #xSpeed = randint(-5,5)
        xSpeed = -5
        #ySpeed = ySpeed+1
        #ySpeed = randint(-5,5)
        ySpeed = 5
        xPos = xPos+randint(-2,2)
    elif aPos == x and bPos == y and xSpeed != 0:
        xSpeed=0-xSpeed
        ySpeed=0-ySpeed
        xPos = xPos+randint(-2,2)
    if xPos>aPos:
        OppDiffx=xPos-aPos
    if xPos<aPos:
        OppDiffx=aPos-xPos
    if OppDiffx <= 15:
    #if xPos==bPos-5:
         #xSpeed = randint(-5,5)
         #ySpeed = randint(-5,5)
         xSpeed = 5
         ySpeed = 5
    elif aPos == xPos and bPos == yPos and xSpeed != 0:
         xSpeed=0-xSpeed
         ySpeed=0-ySpeed

def Score():
    #this part makes the players have seven lives
    LivesLeft = 7 - OppScore
    OppLives = 7 - score
    font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 45)
    text = font.render(str(OppScore), True, white)
    screen.blit(text, [50,5])
    font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 45)
    text = font.render(str(score), True, white)
    screen.blit(text, [650,5])
    if LivesLeft == 0:
        GameOver()
    if OppLives == 0:
        YouWin()

def GameOver():
    global CompletedAll
    font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 75)
    text = font.render("Game over", True, green)
    screen.blit(text, [150, 250])
    time.sleep(2)
    CompletedAll = True

def YouWin():
    global CompletedAll
    font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 75)
    text = font.render("You won!", True, blue)
    screen.blit(text, [150, 250])
    time.sleep(2)
    CompletedAll = True
while not done:
    while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True
            if CompletedAll == True:
                done = True
        screen.fill(white)
        PlayerMallets()
        Puck()
        Collision()
        Score()
        #I suspect that the reason the computer moves very quickly is because of the line underneath which permanently redraws their mallet at another
        #random position but for some reason I can't use a time delay or clock.tick because that causes other problems. I also tried to put it in a while
        #loop so that it redraws every 10 times but that causes notepad c++ not to run it
        xPos = randint(0,350)
        pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Oh god, so many issues here. Globals are bad, backslashes in string don't do what you think, **please comment your code**.

Comment: Thanks, I will do that. I am new to coding. In school last year we used a website called YOUSRC that has a language called ELC. We state that globals at the beginning and can use them in functions without saying global again. I was not used to the error that told me that the local variable was not defined.